# Is there no way to see diff of a merge commit without conflict in gitk

Tags: git, gitk

In `gitk`, the git GUI tool, is there a way to see diff of merge commit. Because it doesn't show me diff of merge commit except the conflicting change which was changed. Or is there anything silly that I'm missing?

Comment: I have never used gitk, and I am sure you have tried, but have you looked for any 'git status' commands?

Answer (score 2):

Select the first parent commit of the merge. Now right click the merge commit, and `Diff selected -> this`. You can show the difference between any two commits this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent merged the other branch yet use squash merge and run the gitgui command this will allow you to see the diff.

```
git merge --squash <other branch>
git gui
```

Comment: But that would require me to first checkout new branch which starts at one of the parent of the merge commit.